# Unity3D Plugin - The Google Play services resources were not found

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, google-play

I'm trying to add GooglePlay Leaderboards and Achievements into my Unity3D plugin, but keep getting the error:

> ........ D/dalvikvm( 6052): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x003f
>   W/dalvikvm( 6052): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1854
>   (common_google_play_services_update_text) in
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string; D/dalvikvm( 6052): VFY: replacing
>   opcode 0x60 at 0x0046 W/dalvikvm( 6052): VFY: unable to resolve static
>   field 1851 (common_google_play_services_unsupported_text) in
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string; D/dalvikvm( 6052): VFY: replacing
>   opcode 0x60 at 0x0066 W/dalvikvm( 6052): VFY: unable to resolve static
>   field 1848 (common_google_play_services_network_error_text) in
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string; D/dalvikvm( 6052): VFY: replacing
>   opcode 0x60 at 0x006d W/dalvikvm( 6052): VFY: unable to resolve static
>   field 1846 (common_google_play_services_invalid_account_text) in
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string; D/dalvikvm( 6052): VFY: replacing
>   opcode 0x60 at 0x0074 W/dalvikvm( 6052): VFY: unable to resolve static
>   field 1850 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string; D/dalvikvm( 6052): VFY: replacing
>   opcode 0x60 at 0x000c E/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 6052): **The Google
>   Play services resources were not found. Check your project
>   configuration to ensure that the resources are included.**
>   D/GooglePlayServices( 6052): onSignInFailed ......

As far as I know iv'e done everything correctly.  Added the "google-play-services_lib" project to my native Java eclipse project, added it as a "Reference", added the "google-play-services.jar" to that project and to the Unity plugins folder.  I have also set "google-play-services.jar" to export its entries and can see in my "R.txt" file the entries are there.

Comment: FYI services still work... stupid Google APIs...

Answer (score 0):

Copy the complete google play services library project (**$android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib**) to the unity Plugins/Android folder.

Comment: I have done that.  Same errors happen even though it still works.  Because everything is working its not a big deal, just very odd.